# I take 1/5th of the following:

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

If I take one 5th of the following what am I doing?

- Sharks
- Tritinite
- Socks
- Bulls
- Fungi
- Canines
- Bridges

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Kissing

Reason:

> take the fifth letter of each word.